# How can i select the distinct values from one col with their latest value from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have 2 columns, names and datetime2. I want to select all distinct names with their latest value for mark according to a thrid col, Date.

```
eg table
name, mark, date
john, 20, 2014-05-17 01:00:01
sally, 30, 2014-05-18 05:00:00
john, 40, 204-05-17 02:00:00
sally, 50, 2014-05-18 04:30:00

result should be - 
john, 40, 2014-05-17 02:00:00
sally, 30, 2014-05-18 05:00:00
```

I tried

```
SELECT name, Mark
FROM table
GROUP BY name, date
```

and

```
select TOP 1 Name, Mark ,date  from table group by name, order by date desc
```

Comment: This is  basic `group by` query.  If you are using SQL, you should know the basics, and `group by` is basic.

Comment: Only group on name, remove date.

Comment: Malk, i get error - date not contained within th eaggregate function

Comment: @Fearghal Then you are doing something else wrong because that's the correct answer

Comment: Apologies, i just realised my question was missing a col - i need to get the name, latest 'mark' col value based on the date col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subSELECT to isolate the record with the latest date and use that to filter the primary query:

```
SELECT name, mark
FROM table t1
WHERE date=(
  SELECT MAX(date)
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t2.name=t1.name
)
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks a mil. I was wondering why the answers coming back were so simple, duh.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good site here on SQL basics which might be useful to you:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

It gives you examples, plus you can test them out by typing your own SQL into the website, or modifying their examples to see the effects.